# Xcode won't let me create a snapshot, because I don't exist

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control

just tried to create a snapshot of one of my projects. It didn't work, and Xcode did throw the following error at me: "Unable to create a snapshot. fatal: You don't exist. Go away!"

Source control commit doesn't work either. Ok, obviously there's something wrong with my local repository. I don't have the slightest idea, what that could possibly be, though. I have not committed in quite a while, but except some updates to Xcode itself, nothing major happened to the project folder, as far as I can remember.

So, what can I do about it? Is it possible to deactivate source control for that project and then start over again with source control with the projects current status? I don't need the previous versions anymore, so that doesn't need to be taken care of.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, but you could send it to the Daily WTF's Error'd, it's a pretty cool error! :)

Comment: It came to me as a surprise, too :(

Comment: @H2C03: unfortunately no. Google it, the error message is genuine. Usually it refers to some git error with being unable to connect to some remote service or something like that, but that doesn't help me because I am dealing with a local repository... On top of that I'm not at all familiar with git..

Answer (score 2):

Looking into the `git` source code, this error message is generated only if

```
pw = getpwuid(getuid());
```

fails.

It indicates that the system wasn't able to find an entry for your user account in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent.

This can happen if your account is removed (via `deluser`, `userdel`, or something else) while you're logged in, or if you don't have read permissions on `/etc/passwd` (the latter should never happen).

Try the following commands at a terminal prompt:

```
whoami

id

ls -l /etc/passwd

grep "^${USER}:" /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the `git` documentation, this is the meaning of your particular error:

```
   You don't exist. Go away!
       The passwd(5) gecos field couldn't be read
```

This typically means the system doesn't know who you are (you'll see this sort of error on a Linux system if you delete someone's user account while they're still logged in).  Is everything else working?  That is, can you log out and log back in without a problem?  Do other terminal commands operate correctly?  What about the `id` command?

Can you interact with your repository on the command line?  What happens if you cd into the directory and try something like `git status`?

WendiKidd's solution of just starting from scratch is probably the simplest thing to do, assuming it works, but you'll lose any change history already associated with your project.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with git and running

```
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

in the terminal fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new project entirely, copying your code etc. files out of the old project, and simply migrating over into a new one (which you could then recommit to another source control directory).  That seems like the easiest solution; this is a very odd error, and I've come across things in the past that are either unfixable or would take more effort to fix than taking 10-15 minutes to just set up a new project.

So that's what I'd recommend--hopefully that will fix your problem, and whatever xcode is mad at is in some hidden file or the .xcodeproj itself, and not in the files you'd need to migrate over.